# SalesForce - Service Cloud Objects

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I'm currently looking for an overview of the objects (like Accounts, Campaigns, Cases, Contact, Contract, Lead, Opportunity, ...) in the Service Cloud in comarison to the Sales Cloud. I know there are function overviews but there is not list of objects related to those versions yet. I need a clear separation with all objects of both. Maybe someone can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look to these schemes:

- [Salesforce Data Model](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/data_model.htm)
- [Sales objects - Sales Cloud](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm)
- [Support objects - Service Cloud](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_support.htm)

hope it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Schema Builder, from Object Manager to know more about Object relationships.

Important things for Service Cloud are -

1. Case object.
2. Email-to-Case
3. Omni Channel
4. Entitlements and Milestones
5. Email Threading.

You can search on Trailhead as well for Service Cloud trails. Will help for sure.

Thanks.